# sed and regex to modify crontab

Tags: regex, sed

I'm stuck on a problem when I'm trying to modify a crontab entry with sed and regex.

Content of the crontab :

```
40 09 21 02 * cd /toto/tata && ./script.sh  1>../log/script_customer1.log 2>../log/script_customer1.err #customer1 #type1 #editable
00 19 21 05 * cd /toto/tata && ./script.sh  1>../log/script_customer2.log 2>../log/script_customer2.err #customer2 #type1 #editable
```

My script :

```
cust_hrt="#customer1 #type1"
crontab -l | sed -e 's/\([0-9]*\) \([0-9]*\) \([0-9]*\) \([0-9]*\) \(.*${cust_hrt} #editable\)/30 22 25 05 \5/'
```

but it doesn't work.
If I try directly with:

```
crontab -l | sed -e 's/\([0-9]*\) \([0-9]*\) \([0-9]*\) \([0-9]*\) \(.*#customer1 #type1 #editable\)/30 22 25 05 \5/'`
```

then it works.

I don't understand.
Did I miss something with the variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable inside single quotes isn't interpolated. It should work if you switch to using double quotes for your sed command.